# Scraped data is not saving to csv file as it keeps returning a blank csv file

Tags: python, csv, selenium-webdriver

My scraper is calling the website and hitting each of the 44 pages and creating a csv file but the csv file is empty. I am returning after each of the functions and saving the data to a csv at the end of the scraper.

Can anyone see what is wrong with my code?

Code:

```
import pandas,requests,bs4,time
from seleniumwire import webdriver
from webdriver_manager.firefox import GeckoDriverManager
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait 
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
import datetime

TODAY = datetime.datetime.today().strftime("%Y%m%d")
SAVE_FILENAME = "/Users/180284/jupyter-1.0.0/pssi_jobs-"+TODAY+".csv"

driver = webdriver.Chrome('~/Desktop/chromedriver_mac64')
driver.implicitly_wait(30)

URL_BASE = "https://jobs.pssi.com/us/en/search-resultskeywords=%22food%20safety%20team%20member%22&s=1"

MAX_PAGE = 44

HEADERS = {
'From': 'myemail'
}

def interceptor(request):
    del request.headers['From']
    request.headers['From'] = HEADERS["From"]

driver.request_interceptor = interceptor

def parse_job_post_div(div_html):
    soup = bs4.BeautifulSoup(div_html)
    job_ls = soup.findAll("div",{"class":"information"})
    job_data = []
    for job in job_ls:
        job_listing = job.find("div",{"class":"information"}).get_text(separator=", ").strip()
        title = job.find("span",{"role":"heading"}).get_text(separator=", ").strip()
        job_location = job.find("p",{"class":"job-info"}).get_text(separator=", ").strip()
        new_row = {"job_listing":job,"title":title,"job_location":job_location}
        job_data.append(new_row)
    
    return job_data
    
def get_data(wd):
    job_postings = driver.find_element(By.CLASS_NAME, "information")
    html = job_postings.get_attribute("innerHTML")
    parsed = parse_job_post_div(html)

    return pandas.DataFrame(parsed)


def process_page(url):
    driver.get(url)
    master_data = []
    i = 0
    while True:
        df = get_data(driver)
        master_data.append(df)
        if i == (MAX_PAGE - 1):
        break
        driver.find_element(By.XPATH, "//span[@class='icon icon-arrow-right']").click()

        time.sleep(10)
        print(i)
        i+=1
    
    return pandas.concat(master_data,ignore_index=True)
    
data = process_page(URL_BASE)
data.to_csv(SAVE_FILENAME)
```

`
I have tried the above code.

Answer (score 0):

The first problem I found in your code is that the `job_ls` is an empty list, i.e. `soup.findAll("div",{"class":"information"})` doesn't find anything.

Moreover, `job_postings` contains only one webelement (i.e. the first job of the list) instead of all 10 jobs shown in the page, that's because you used `.find_element` instead of `.find_elements`. As a result of these and other problems, `process_page(URL_BASE)` returns an empty dataframe.

In this case you can speed up the process and use less code using directly selenium instead of `bs4`

```
driver.get(URL_BASE)
driver.implicitly_wait(30)
MAX_PAGE = 4
titles, locations, descriptions = [], [], []

for i in range(MAX_PAGE):
    print('current page:',i+1,end='\r')

    titles       += [title.text                  for title in driver.find_elements(By.CSS_SELECTOR, '.information > span[role=heading]')]
    locations    += [loc.text.replace('\n',', ') for loc   in driver.find_elements(By.CSS_SELECTOR, '.information > p[class=job-info]')]
    descriptions += [title.text                  for title in driver.find_elements(By.CSS_SELECTOR, '.information > p[data-ph-at-id=jobdescription-text')]
    
    if i < MAX_PAGE-1:
        driver.find_element(By.XPATH, "//span[@class='icon icon-arrow-right']").click()
    else:
        break

df = pandas.DataFrame({'title':titles,'location':locations,'description':descriptions})
df.to_csv(SAVE_FILENAME, index=False)
```

and `df` will be something like

[image]